# Python: 64bit Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working with `numpy` on a 32bit system (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS).

Can I expect my code to work fluently, in the same manner, on a 64bit (Ubuntu) system?

Does `numpy` have an compatibility issues with 64bit `python`?

Comment: Have you checked the numpy site? Why not look at their bug tracker and see if anything's shown up?

Comment: I've used numpy/scipy on 64-bit system with no 64-bit issues whatsoever for the past 4 years.  (And it was about 35% faster doing 64-bit double math then using the core 2 duo in 32-bit mode.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy has been used on 64-bit systems of all types for years now. I doubt you will find anything new that doesn't show up elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are official Ubuntu packages and the installation instructions explicitly mention AMD64 as a target plattform: [Installing SciPy/Linux](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux#head-a90c32e254c541dc441761308310a6f21f9b53e2).

The code uses type identifiers with exact size definitions (e.g. "float64") internally, so the code will also be portable between plattforms. You should notice a performance impact for the better or worse depending on the type of algorithms you run.

Comment: thank you. what do you mean by `AMD64 as a target plattform`?

Comment: @user326424: That means it can be compiled for 64 bit processors.